# Problems connecting over PPP with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: raspbian, serial, serial-console, ppp

I am currently attempting to set up PPP between my Pi and my Ubuntu 13.04 Toshiba Satellite A105 via the Serial Cable, as per this site: http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection.

I successfully (I think) started PPP Daemon on my pi via `sudo pppd` it worked for a second then gave me this:

> pppd: The remote system is required to authenticate itself 
>   pppd: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.

I ignored this because of the RPi Serial Connection page it says:

> Step 1: login to the Raspberry Pi over the serial cable and run the Point-to- Point Protocol Daemon: 
>   `sudo pppd` 
>   Some garbage will start appearing in the terminal. 
>   This is the cue to quit your terminal
>   program and proceed to step two.

So I did this and then proceeded on to step two. This is where my problem begins (I think.)

I started another terminal for connecting to my Pi and entered the command given to me in step two:
`sudo pppd -detach noauth proxyarp /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 10.0.0.1:10.0.0.2 passive local maxfail 0 nocrtscts xonxoff`

This is where I have trouble. It tells me this:

```
nate@excelion-Satellite-A105:~$ :~$ sudo p-detach noauth proxyarp /dev/ttyUSB0-0 115200 10.0.0.1:10.0.0.2 passive local maxfail 0 nocrtscts xonxoff
[sudo] password for nate: 
pppd: unrecognized option '/dev/ttyUSB0-0'
pppd version 2.4.5
Usage: pppd [ options ], where options are:
    <device>    Communicate over the named device
    <speed>     Set the baud rate to <speed>
    <loc>:<rem> Set the local and/or remote interface IP
            addresses.  Either one may be omitted.
    asyncmap <n>    Set the desired async map to hex <n>
    auth        Require authentication from peer
        connect <p>     Invoke shell command <p> to set up the serial line
    crtscts     Use hardware RTS/CTS flow control
    defaultroute    Add default route through interface
    file <f>    Take options from file <f>
    modem       Use modem control lines
    mru <n>     Set MRU value to <n> for negotiation
See pppd(8) for more options.
```

What am I doing wrong? My Ubuntu system is totally up to date (just ran apt-get upgrade last night) and I just installed ppp onto my Pi about 20 minutes ago ( as of 2:30 10/31/2013)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please, look carefully at your command line, I don't believe there's a device called `/dev/ttyUSB0-0` in your system, you should have `-0` part separated from the file name or removed altogether.